# How to get browser cookies in Perl?

Tags: php, perl, cookies, cgi, session-cookies

Trying to get browser cookies which have set through PHP. But unable to get same cookies in Perl script. Kindly help me anyone and save my life.

```
  use CGI;

  $query = new CGI;

  print $query->header;

  $cookid = $query->cookie('PHPSESSID_port443');
```

Comment: this is the actual way to get a cookie with cgi. I think your problem is either the name of the cookie, or how this script of yours is being called

Comment: just keeping on top of the file and run on chrome browser. still getting same result. have you any sample code?
here is error: Can't locate object method "header" via package "GLOB" at <file path>

Comment: if you dont mind post the whole script and the whole error

Comment: approx 60,000 line code so not possible to paste here and also there is security issue. 
package miniserv;
use Socket;
use POSIX;
use Time::Local;
eval "use Time::HiRes;";

use CGI;
$query = new CGI;
#print $query->header;
$cookid = $query->cookie('state');

Comment: Was there a recent operating system update? Sounds like your CGI module is broken.

Comment: See also [PHP::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::Session)

Comment: Please describe what unexpected behaviour you're seeing. What ends up in `$cookid`?

Comment: Also note: Indirect object notation (`$query = new CGI`) works most of the time but it will confuse you when you trip over one of the cases where it doesn't work. Far better to use `query = CGI->new`.

Comment: if your script has 60K lines then you surely doing something wrong. despite that fact, it is very hard to debug something that you dont see. I suggest you reinstall your modules and break your script to smaller ones so you can debug it

Comment: using PHP::Session but getting directory not found. @HåkonHægland
/tmp/sess_: No such file or directory at

Comment: tried with query = CGI->new but same issue @DaveCross

Comment: miniserv.pl file using as Apache server for webmin so i think not possible to brakdown @Tch

Comment: if its webmin you are using, then miniserv.pl has no `use cgi` in it as far as I remember and its about 5-6k lines not 60k. did you try to alter the miniserv.pl file yourself?

Comment: Yep! it's approx 6k sorry for that i was typo error. some custom lines there so no possibility to change this file. Another method/options?

Comment: by the way there is a `$header` hash in miniserv.pl that has very useful headers in it like cookie. you might wanna take a look in there, maybe you will find your cookie. and remove your `use cgi; and stuf...` from the script

Comment: @SoftuvoTest: Oh, I wasn't suggesting that my change would fix your problem. It was just a general piece of advice to improve your Perl programming.

Comment: @SoftuvoTest: *using PHP::Session but getting directory not found* - It's not a standard Perl module. You'll need to install it separately.

Comment: @SoftuvoTest: What do you see if you call `cookie()` without parameters to get a list of the available cookies? Have you debugged the raw HTTP transaction to see what cookies are being sent?

Comment: @DaveCross Yes, i am beginner in PERL so that's why am getting this :) but need resolution yet. Could you plz suggest me a link for the same?

Comment: @SoftuvoTest: You were given a link above. But I don't think that will help. PHP::Session is for reading session files. You're having trouble reading the cookie. Did you try my other suggestions? What happened?